# SSRS : Date format expression in Text box

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

In the SSRS Report I need to show the below format in TextBox.

Example: By default, it should pick a current date.

**Data Reporting

18, April 2018**

How to write the Expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Format(Now(),"MMMM dd,yyyy") which would yield April 18,2018.
You could check this for more formats:
https://dattatreysindol.files.wordpress.com/2011/02/ssrs_date_time_formatting_demo_1016x5701.png

Answer (score 0):

```
="**Data Reporting "&Format(today,"dd, MMM yyyy")&"**"
```